# Probability of Picking samples

Tags: probability

I have a question I'm working on but I need some help around the process.

Consider picking samples of an engineering material that has a 5% chance of being faulty. How many samples do you need before there is a 90% chance of finding at least one faulty sample?

I know for this we need to use Bernoulli's trials and I know the Probability Mass function of faulty sample is p(x)= 5%. from Bernoulli's trials I know

p(x)=(n) * p^x* (1-p^x)^n-x
x

I know there is one faulty sample, which is x=1 and I need to find the Value of "n". Is it right direction I'm heading?. I just wanted an confirmation

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. You are trying to answer the question of exactly one trial with likelihood 90%. The question requires one *or more*!

Consider using complements instead. How many trials do you need to complete before the probability of them all being success is 10% or less?

This is simply the probability of success 0.95, assuming independence, to the power of $n$, being not more than 0.1, which can be easily solved with logarithms.

Comment: Thanks . so you are saying I can't use Bernoulli's trials since it is one trial?. Also what you are suggesting is to get the Complement of the P(x) =1 -p(x)= 1 -.95= 0.05. From that How can determine "n"?. Could you please let me know

Comment: As I've said in the answer, using logarithms to solve the equation with exponent $n$, finding at what point the power of 0.9 reaches 0.1